# Load balancer giving failed_to_pick_backend with internet network endpoint group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have a load balancer setup pointing to an external url via [internet network endpoint group](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/internet-neg-concepts#health_checks) (internet NEG)

Now the load balancer returns `502` status code & I see `failed_to_pick_backend` in the logs. Also the monitoring tab of the load balancer shows `INVALID_BACKEND` next to the internet NEG I've defined. I've attached screenshots of the view for clarity, latter one is the one that's failing. I've checked the NEGs and they seem identical.

[image: working example]

[image]

All the suggestions so far mention fixing health checks, but as seen from the docs, internet NEGs does not support health checks.
I was able to create working setup through the UI, but when replicating the setup via terraform, things starts to fail. The only difference I saw was that the setup done via UI, the appropriate forwarding rule had ipVersion: IPV4, but that was not possible to setup through terraform since it takes either ipVersion or ip and I gave the resource ip.

So, what could cause `failed_to_pick_backend` & `INVALID_BACKEND` with setup like mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question from another post: https://serverfault.com/a/1065279/965524

`google_compute_global_network_endpoint` needs to be created before `google_compute_backend_service` is created so you need to set `depends_on = [google_compute_global_network_endpoint.endpoint]` to your `google_compute_backend_service`. Otherwise you will hit errors like described in the question.